# Convolution and Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

Im stuck at a rather simple question. The problem is this

Solve the integral

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin [5(t-u)]\sin 6t} {u (t-u)}du
$$
And this is just the convolution of $$\frac{\sin 5t}{t} \quad \text{and} \quad\frac{\sin6t}{t}$$
so my aim was to take the Fourier transformation of this, put it together and the use the inverse transformation. The funny thing is that I am stuck at the transformation, I can't find it in my table. Maybe someone can help me with this?

I will add a question to this, can you start with the inverse transformation and then combine it and after that use the transformation? The reverse order to say.

Comment: The Fourier transform of $\frac{\sin(t)}{t}$ is a multiple of the indicator function of $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Shouldn't the denominator be $t(t-u)$?

Comment: no but it should be $du$ not $dt$, changed it now.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean Ian?

Comment: Just try calculating the inverse FT of the indicator function of $[-1,1] $. You will see what I mean. (Note that sin (t)/t, sometimes with a normalization, is called sinc, which might be in your table.)